# Vue select using getJSON

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using getJSON to call an external web service which returns an array of strings.
I have a select which is bind to the JSON data. But the dropdown is not displaying the data. IE console displays the array of data. if I output this as a table, it displays on the browser. Any ideas?

eg: json return data (IE console):

```
["process1\\test1","process2\\test1","process3\\test1","process3\\test2"]
```

code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        var app1 = new Vue({
            el: '#app1',
            data: {     
                selected: '',
                options: []
            },
            methods: {
                getData: function () {
                    $.getJSON("https://testapp/getmyprocesses?callback=?", function (data) {
                        this.options = data;
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    });
                }
            },
            mounted: function () {
                this.getData();
            }     
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<div id="app1">

    <select v-model = "selected">
     <option value="">Select a Process</option>
      <option v-for = "option in options" v-bind:value="option">
        {{ option }}
      </option>
    </select>
   <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
    </div>
```

Thanks
Venky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use arrow function `(data)=>` instead of `function (data) {...` as follow:

```
     getData: function () {
                $.getJSON("https://testapp/getmyprocesses?callback=?",(data)=> {
                    this.options = data;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                });
            }
```

with the your old syntax you should have this error :

> this is undefined

Comment: This is correct, because "this" in the callback is in the different context.